# flask database view returning only one item when using all

Tags: python, model-view-controller, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm confused about the behaviour of my model. I've got the model built off the mysql database, and it returns the correct count of 89, but I cannot iterate through it for some reason.
My controller is:

```
@app.route('/calendar/<date>')
def calendar(date):
    cur_date = datetime.datetime.today()
    cur_date = cur_date + datetime.timedelta(days=int(date))
    cur_date = str(cur_date).split(' ')[0]
    x = earnings_calendar.query.filter_by(Date=cur_date).all()
    print type(x)
    for i in x:
        print i


    return render_template('calendar.html', data=x)
```

But when I perform:

```
{% for i in data %}
    {{i['Qtr']}}
{% endfor %}
```

In the view, only one item shows. The length of x is 1, but if I change all to count it shows 89. How do I iterate through to show all 89?

I have not defined a representation, do I need to? I thought it was optional.

Comment: Are you sure that there's more than one entry that matches on cur_date?  What happens if you write the query by hand?

Comment: I wrote the query in workbench and it returned the 89 rows. Since the count matches I know the flask model sees it, but for some reason all is only returning one. I'm super new to models though, so maybe I did the migration wrong. It just seems like the model does see the data, since the count matches.

Comment: We're not entirely sure that the model sees it yet.  Can you print out any metadata from `data`?  Can you inspect it in a debugger?

Comment: Please show the rest of the controller function.

Comment: It does get the count correct, so it must see the data somehow. I dont know how to print out metadata or test with a debugger, do you maybe have a link for this info? I'm going off a book that only has a small chapter on this, primarily made for new DBs not migrations.

I added the full controller for that page Daniel.